# Autorun exe when plugin in usb

Tags: windows, usb, autorun

I'm trying to run an exe application when i plug in my usb. I have created an `autorun.inf` with this code but it does nothing when I plug it in

```
[autorun]
open=putty.exe
```

How can I achive this? Using windows 7 btw

Answer (score 1):

The autorun function on USB has been disabled by Microsoft in Windows 7 and higher.  Have two options to work around autorun limitations:

1. Use of special USB drives that present themselves as CD drives to the computer (for example, U3 flash drives). These USB sticks can take advantage of autorun functionality like any other CD. 
   Experienced users may try to create a flash drive with a CD-ROM partition from a typical USB stick manually. I found an useful article which helped me to create own autorun USB : http://visualdesigning.com/articles/how-to-create-autorun-usb-drive/
2. The other option for autorun functionality is to preinstall a program that scans for USB sticks in USB ports and executes exe thus emulating autorun feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
[autorun]
icon=putty.exe
open=putty.exe
action=Click “OK” to start your apps!
```

Once the Autorun box comes up, Click on Ok. Thats it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was annoyed by wanting autorun several years ago, so I wrote a small utility meant to be run on a few personal machines. I'm not sure what state it is in regarding Windows 8, etc., but it may be something like what you want.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ignitionkey/

edit: I know sourceforge is terrible, I did not know this in 2012, sorry.